# Доступ к локальной сети через VPN

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn

Могу ли я получить доступ с компьютера 10.0.0.2 к подсети 192.168.11.0 напрямую (сейчас можно только по ssh подключиться к 10.0.0.22, а затем получить доступ к подсети 192.168.11.0) ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я понял вопрос, 10.0.0.22 находится в одной сети с 10.0.0.2 и в локальной сети с 192.168.11.0, собственно, 10.0.0.2 не будет иметь доступ к 192.168.11.0, потому что они находятся по итогу не в одной сети

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## на 10.0.0.22

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.11.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

и чтоб сохранить

```
apt install iptables-persistent
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
echo net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

## на 10.0.0.2

ip r a  192.168.11.0/24 via 10.0.0.22

что сохранить используйте интерфейс с которого делали впн подключение